AI Tools for Tuning SQL Server?
Are there any strong and accurate AI-based utilities out there that can help identify problems with and suggest better-tuned alternatives for deficient queries, and that can analyze and provide useful feedback for execution plans?  I am a learning Administrator with responsibility for 2016 and 2022 databases.  Any suggestions would be appreciated!


Are there any strong and accurate AI-based utilities out there that can help identify problems with and suggest better-tuned alternatives for deficient queries, and that can analyze and provide useful feedback for execution plans?

Nope, there are not. It's too complex of a general problem for AI to be able to sufficiently and repeatedly handle currently.
Microsoft has created some of their own automation tools baked into SQL Server and Azure such as:

The Database Engine Tuning Advisor
Missing Index Suggestions
Azure Automatic Tuning
Microsoft Copilot in Azure (in preview)

Though they are limited and aren't based on a generic-AI, rather are custom tailored towards the database engine they belong to.

Microsoft Copilot skills in Azure SQL Database (preview)

I have seen that ChatGPT, Copilot and Gemini (among others, I'd guess) do have some capabilities to parse and provide some relatively narrow feedback on modest queries.  It's better than nothing and occasionally there are some useful nuggets that come from those engines.  I was thinking more advanced though.  Thanks for the reply.

@AccidentalDBA_CO No problem! Yea of course ChatGPT for example, can be fed a text prompt asking it to write a particular query and it can write code that will more or less be accurate for most simpler use cases. But doing so in a performant way is going to be something it can't repeatedly do, especially the more complex the problem is. It doesn't have access to all of the information necessary to do so, such as the qualitative and quantitative properties of the data itself, i.e. the statistics for example. Think of it this way, the database engine is designed to give a performant execution...

...plan specifically targeted to the query you wrote based on all of the information it has available. It's designed to give you something good, not something not good (which would be nonsensical). So it would be near impossible for a decoupled general purpose AI system that has less access to relevant information about your database to outperform the targeted database engine.
